# Using a jquery plugin in an android application

Tags: java, android, jquery

I want to develop an android application which contains a Date of birth field.But i dont want to use the traditional datepicker control.So i found a jquery plugin birthday picker Link:http://abecoffman.com/stuff/birthdaypicker/

But i dont know how to implement it in my android code:

Can anyone tell me how to implement it in my android code?Also does jquery work only for html type of designs?

Can someone also suggest a good solution for implementing date of birth in an android form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed a WebView in your application. Then you can use HTML, javascript or jQuery code in it. In a native Android application you can't directly use jQuery. You should use it through an HTML page.

However, you don't have to use jQuery for this. You can achieve the same layouts with spinners. Then you can intialize a Date or GregorianCalendar object with the picked values.